# Remove all Elements With a Custom Null Value Java

Tags: java, list, null, remove-if

So I've been working on some code and I have a custom class named word. From here I have a list of words (dupeWordList) and would like to remove all words from that list that have a value of null. Keep in mind, value is variable inside the word class. The word class contains the following stored values:
Frequency (int)
Value (String)

Is there anyway to remove all words that when you call word.getValue() it returns null? Surely there is a way to do this. If anything I could loop through the entire list and do this process.

Code:

```
List<Word> dupeWordList;
dupeWordList = new ArrayList<>(wordList);
dupeWordList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

Comment: in java 8 you can use `dupeWordList.removeIf(e -> e.getValue() == null)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java 8 you could do

```
dupeWordList.removeIf(e -> e.getValue() == null)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Ill accept this answer as soon as it lets me.